# Get row-column coordinates of all matches in Excel table

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of dates and a variable date range and need to find all matches for rows and columns where a date in the table lie within the range of my start/end date range.

As a (downscaled) example of my case:

```
Start date: 01Jan2018
End date: 30Jun2018
```

Table with dates:

```
{01Jan2018; 01Feb2018; 01Apr2018}
{17Mar2018; 05Jun2018; 16Aug2018}
{11Apr2018; 01Jul2018; }
```

Some fields in the table may be blank if no date has been entered yet. I believe I can make a comparison array by running the start/end dates against the date array, e.g. with

```
=--(array>=start_date)*(array<=end_date)
```

which would output

```
{1;1;1}
{1;1;0}
{1;0;0}
```

But what's the next step to get from here to a vertical list of row-column sets where row and column number is in separate cells? From the example above I would need a list like:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
1 2
2 2
1 3
```

I have other arrays sized like the date array that I need to match the found coordinates against to look up other data using the found coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(AND(A4>=$B$1,A4<=$B$2),"In","Out")
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I like the approach. Think I overlooked a method with temporary or helper cells. My table is a 2d matrix and quite large but fixed in size for now, so will require quite the helper sheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the size of you array, you need to create list of all coordinates (formulas to generate it at the end of the post). Then bring the value from this coordinate, check against your condition (column "C") and filter where `TRUE` (column "D").
[image: data]

And with formulas shown:
[image: formulas]

Result (highlighted with green):

[image: result]

Here are two formulas generating the list of columns and rows based on data range size:

```
A9: =IF(B9="end";"end";MOD(ROW(C1)-1+COLUMNS($A$1:$C$3);COLUMNS($A$1:$C$3))+1)
B9: =IF(1+INT((ROW(C1)-1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$C$3))>COLUMNS($A$1:$C$3);"end";1+INT((ROW(C1)-1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$C$3)))
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach is in nature like the one suggested by @Error 1004. I like that it takes into account that the table is a 2d matrix. I am still curious to see if someone has an all-in-one formula to spit out row/column sets, though :)

Comment: Just added formulas generating row/column sets :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a long formula, but basically this one formula will:

1. Get the relevant date using index (based on the row() ) and the matrix (3x3)
2. Conversion to 1 & 0's based on whether it's between the dates
3. Return the Column / Row number if 1

For Column:

```
=IF(--(INDEX($A$4:$C$6,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/3,0),IF(MOD((ROW()-1),3)=0,3,MOD((ROW()-1),3)))>=$B$1)*(INDEX($A$4:$C$6,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/3,0),IF(MOD((ROW()-1),3)=0,3,MOD((ROW()-1),3)))<=$B$2)<>0,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/3,0),"n/a")
```

For Row:

```
=IF(--(INDEX($A$4:$C$6,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/3,0),IF(MOD((ROW()-1),3)=0,3,MOD((ROW()-1),3)))>=$B$1)*(INDEX($A$4:$C$6,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/3,0),IF(MOD((ROW()-1),3)=0,3,MOD((ROW()-1),3)))<=$B$2)<>0,IF(MOD((ROW()-1),3)=0,3,MOD((ROW()-1),3)),"n/a")
```

[Image of the excel solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAE2O.png)